# How to setup Substrate Private network to support more than 8 nodes

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

We are running a substrate private blockchain network. We are able to add a total of 8 nodes but are not able to increase more than that.

For the 9th node: 9th node is not starting to sync after performing node authorization. So here I am trying to understand do we have any limit in the no of connecting nodes in Substrate private network.

And Is there a way we can increase the no of nodes in the same network?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is there any error you are facing while adding the 9th node?

Comment: @ImmanuelJohn There are no errors, but node sync is not happening for the 9th node. I could find some suggestions like adding max-peers flag to the configuration but not able to identify the exact file to update this flag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can trying using the `--in-peers` and `--out-peers` flags to set the desired peers count.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use auto-discovery?

I encountered this before, but I'm not sure if they were caused by the same reason.

Try:

1. setting up a bootnode and use `--bootnodes`
2. manually setting up the `--port` for each of them

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `pallet_node_authorization` then the default limit is 8 which is set in the runtime config. You can increase/update this number accordingly. I have set this to 512 in the below example.

```rust
    parameter_types! {
        pub const MaxWellKnownNodes: u32 = 512;
        pub const MaxPeerIdLength: u32 = 128;
    }
    
    impl pallet_node_authorization::Config for Runtime {
        type Event = Event;
        type MaxWellKnownNodes = MaxWellKnownNodes;
        type MaxPeerIdLength = MaxPeerIdLength;
        type AddOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
        type RemoveOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
        type SwapOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
        type ResetOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
        type WeightInfo = ();
    }
```